# extend app.user in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

I use Twig for my project and I wanna extend global object app.user without adding property in my UserClass. I mean this:

I have UserClass:

```
<?php
namespace Test\CoreBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\CoreBundle\Repositories\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

And I have Repository:

```
<?php
namespace Test\CoreBundle\Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getCountPosts () {
        //some code

        return 10;
    }
}
```

How can i get access to UserRepository's method getCountPosts inside Twig templates?

Comment: I assume you have a `OneToMany` relation with `Post` entity. What about `{{ app.user.posts|length }}` ?

Comment: Did you consider creating a twig extension and exposing the repository's function via that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because business logic has to be in the controllers. You can create extra methods in the entities and call them in a Twig template.

```
<?php
namespace Test\CoreBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\CoreBundle\Repositories\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCountPosts () {
        //some code
        return 10;
    }

}
```

And in your Twig file

```
{{ app.user.getCountPosts() }}
```

Comment: `app.user.countPosts` would do